# OEMToCharW returns wrong characters

Tags: windows, delphi, unicode, command-line, delphi-7

I read the input buffer from a console application (CMD) like this:

```
var
pBuffer     : array [0..2400] of Widechar;
dBuffer     : array [0..2400] of WideChar;
CReadBuffer : Cardinal;
BytesRead   : Cardinal;
begin
// ....
 ReadFile(BuffHandle, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, BytesRead, nil);
 pBuffer[BytesRead] := #0; // Finish/End the WideString
 OemToCharW(pBuffer, dBuffer);
 MessageBoxW (0, dBuffer, '', 0);
// ....
end;
```

For some reason I get weird chars...
CMD should have the oem charset. I used OEMtoCharA before and it worked fine.
What do I do wrong?

Thanks for help.

EDIT: 
I use Delphi7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, CMD has the OEM charset, which means the pBuffer should be declared as

```
pBuffer: array[0..2400] of AnsiChar;
```

Now try again (can't check this right now myself).

It transpires that the declaration of [`OemToCharW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647493.aspx) is incorrect in Delphi 7. In Delphi 7 the first parameter is incorrectly declared as `PWideChar` when it should be `PAnsiChar`. You should redeclare `OemToCharW` correctly in your code and possibly consider using [`OemToCharBuffW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647494.aspx) instead.

Comment: good thought! The only problem is that oemtocharW requires a widechar array in the first parameter. :/

Comment: Funnily, `OemToCharW` is declared as `function OemToCharW(lpszSrc: PWideChar; lpszDst: PWideChar): BOOL; stdcall;` in D2007, but as `function OemToCharW(lpszSrc: PAnsiChar; lpszDst: PWideChar): BOOL; stdcall;` in XE2. So D2007 seems to be wrong.

Comment: I forgot to say I use Delphi7. But how is that possible. The WindowsAPI should be the same... I tried it with UTF-8 but no luck.

Comment: I just changed the winapi to PAnsiChar for the first parameter. Same result as the snippet I posted. The characters are shown fine (ASCII Chars). But LineFeeds and UNICODE chars are either question marks or music notes and other weird chars...

Comment: I also used OemToCharBuffW still no luck and same result.

Comment: The results you get can differ with the font. Some fonts can't display certain characters. What do you mean with UNICODE chars? If there are characters that are not usual on your OS, try a Unicode font. And single line feeds (LF, or #10) should be converted to CR+LF (#13#10) first.